# ImportError create_namedtuple_class Django Modeltranslation

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

I have an error while trying to use `django-modeltranslation` 0.18.3 in Django 2.2.

Here's the end of the traceback:

```
[...]
    from django.db.models.utils import create_namedtuple_class
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_namedtuple_class' from 'django.db.models.utils' (/home/me/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/utils.py)
```

I can't figure what's wrong with modeltranslations and with django. I recreated a clean venv, nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their CHANGELOG does not mention it, but they started using some code relative to django >= 3 in `v0.18.3`. Version `0.18.2` is the last one that supports django 2.2.